# Offline usage of OpenStreetMap or alternatives

Tags: openstreetmap, windows-phone

I'm planning to implement an offline map solution for windows phone using open street maps. To achieve this, would I need to download complete OSM database first and than use it? Or is possible to fetch it on-demand and store it locally?

If OSM is not the best solution what else could be used to have an offline maps application? Offline data would be required only for about 3-5 cities, not more than that.

Comment: "It depends". What do you need the map for? Which cities? What resolution(s)? Is OSM licensing OK? Is commercial source viable? There are a lot of options, and it would help if you can tell us more about your problem space.

Comment: Nokia [aka HERE] and Google (on Android) have Offline solutions for mobile devices.

Comment: you can load OSM data into your own PostGIS database and use tiling script such Mapnik and TileStache to render the maps, but that would not works for mobile.

Comment: @BradHards The map would be used to suggest routes alternate routes etc. The basic aim is to download/sync data for few cities like New York, London etc. The need is that user doesn't have to traverse the map for caching it, instead the data could be synced automatically by selecting a city, say from a drop down.
- No particular requirements for Resolution
- OSM licensing looks OK, any commercial option could be given a look as well

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the solution at:

http://www.mapdotnet.com/index.php/developers-center/easyblog/entry/offline-support-for-rim-html5-mapping

On this page there is a link to a Visual Studio 2012 project you can download which provides offline mapping support for Windows 8 - but since it uses Phonegap, it can also target Windows 8 phone, iOS, android using phonegap build.

The code-base creates a tile quad-tree on the fly when online and saves it to the device file system. When offline, it automatically retrieves the tiles from the file system cache. Bing, Google, Nokia, OSM and MapQuest are supported by the map control used in the sample (see www.mapsjs.com for more information on the map control and JavaScript API).

Given the TOUs for the various content providers, OSM is a good start. I'd also look at MapQuest. You would most likely be in violation of Google's and Bing's TOUs taking their content offline with the above approach.

Comment: It looks promising, but is there a possibility that I can download data specifically for a few cities without first having to traverse the map to cache the data locally?